# Drop NA while unstack

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this:

```
field             
date     source   colA colB
20180101 source1  1    Nan
         source2  Nan  2
20180102 source1  3    Nan
         source2  NaN  4

...
```

It is guaranteed that colA will always have data for source1 and never for source 2. Similar for colB, it will always have data for source2 but never source1.

Now I want to do an unstack and reorder so I can have something like this:

```
source   source1   source2
field    colA      colB
date
20180101 1         2
20180102 3         4
...
```

But the problem is that when I unstack, I got columns with all NAs for source1 colB and source2, colA. I do not want to do a dropna after the unstack because I feel there is a chance to lose important info. Is there anyway to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for Series with removed `NaN`s with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for `DataFrame` with `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
df = df.stack().unstack([1,2])
print (df)
source   source1 source2
            colA    colB
date                    
20180101     1.0     2.0
20180102     3.0     4.0
```